# Is my question suited for SO, if not where should I ask it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am planning to make an application to digitize and organize documents that a company, or forum, etc may have.

The first thing that came to my mind was:

- How should I look for possible competitors that already have their product on the market?

To see what I am against, so I believe this question would be rather flamed if posted on the SO.

Other things I was thinking of:

- Once I know about the other companies doing this same application I am planning, what should I consider before taking the step to do it or look for something else?
- Is there a public or a good resource where I should look first about the type of application I am planning to create?
- Would SO be a good place for this sort of questions or where should I go with those question I have?

**Just wanted to add here since I stated on the comment answer below, that what concerns me the most is the attitude of the community whenever a post that may not suit it or is subjective or don't suit it at all, people go all out to bang it with negative votes without leaving a comment or giving the moderators a chance to move it, hence why I asked here first.**

PS: hope I didn't do anything wrong by posting this here as well. If I'm missing a tag please let me know to added to it, I wasn't sure of what other tags I should use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment, I would go to [Startups](//startups.stackexchange.com/). There is a nice and competent group of users.

SO is not the place to ask these questions for certain. They are not programming related, but more marketing and especially competitor analysis.

And call those people competitors, not adversaries. Maybe they become partners in the future. And you do not want to fight against them, but build a better product and therefore compete by bringing your talents to the plate instead of destroying them. Enough is done through lawyers.

Leaving the meta level and giving you some tips: do surveys on how other people solve the problem of document digitization and management. As others pointed out, SU would be a good place to start. From this you will gain knowledge about the existing (huge) field of solutions, and even as important you will get some key words to conduct research (f.e. using Google) like "Document Management", "Archiving", "Categorization", "OCR", and such. I'm sure you know most of them.

Read the feature lists of these products, look whether the feature list you had in mind differs enough to dare to join the competition. Maybe making a complementary product to an existing one would be a possibility?

Comment: Thanks i will update that, i was actually looking for the word to describe it better but my mind went blank at the momment and i ended up with adversaries hehehe ... Yes i do belive that can happen, it was mostly because of my english.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you should ask your question where you think it best belongs and then there is an established community including moderators who will move your question if necessary.

If you are not confident then take the time to look around at the other established communities.

There are plenty that already exist (see links in the footer) and also some of the many sites in beta. To see a list of all the sites [look here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

There is a proposal site that is probably more suitable, but is not in the beta stage just yet: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business

I suggest you try and get involved within that community, add some example questions and try and get it off the ground.

Comment: What worries me is not making the question in the wrong site but the HIGH VOLUME of people that threats it as something bad and run to negativate you and don't even drop a comment hence why i would avoid creating a question that i am not sure of where it belong instead of creating a question, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Prix please see edited answer with link to start-up business proposal site. I suggest this may be the best place for your questions.

Comment: sounds like a plan thanks, i will check it but will still be looking for others to give their point of view here ...

Comment: @Prix:  Why would it bother you that people may downvote an off-topic question?  (Personally, I'd just vote to close if I found that on SO.)

Comment: @David Thornley it does not bother me they downvote me it bothers me when there are downvotes without explainations ... i am the type of person that does not like to be negativated without knowing why to overcome it and to learn from it. if people just go in and negative it, i won't know why, depending on the case i might even look at it over and over and still think it is fine untill someone points me out that it was not for this or that.

Answer (score 2):

To research existing software, I would try [**Superuser.com. Super User is a Q&A site for computer enthusiasts.**](https://superuser.com/).

Your question isn't a programming question, but it's clearly about software, so I would ask, `what software do all y'all use to digitalize and organize large archives of documents?`. I'd leave out the personal story, since it just occludes the question itself.

There's quite a few. "what software is there to do [blah]," questions on Superuser.

PS: I would also try:
[image]

Comment: That is quiet a good point of reworking the question, i didnt thinked of that way of putting it, thanks a lot... about the google, if u notice even with your link there were lots of other pages with nothing related to what i was looking for not that i think it is bad or anything, its search afterall but i would like to build something more strict before going into google :)